# Essentially Smooth Function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is essentially smooth if $f\in \mathcal{C}^1$ and $||\nabla f(x)||_* \to \infty$ as $||x||\to\infty$. What is the intuition of essentially smoothness? ($||.||_*$ denotes dual norm)

Comment: What is norm star?

Comment: It is dual norm.

Comment: Isn't the definition that the norm of the gradient approaches infinity as $x$ approaches any point on the boundary of $D$?

Comment: @littleO: Thanks for your comment. I thought maybe there is a more intuitive meaning for this fact.